Optimizing Variable Combinations to Maximize a Classification
I am working with a dataset where users interact via an app or a website, and I need to determine the optimal combination of variables (x1, x2, ... xn) that will maximize the number of users classified as "APP Lovers." According to the business rule, a user is considered an "APP Lover" if they use the app more than 66% of the time.
Here’s a simplified example of the data structure:
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "ID": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    "variable": ["x1", "x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x3", "x3", "x3"],
    "Favourite": ["APP", "APP", "WEB", "APP", "WEB", "APP", "APP", "APP", "WEB"]
})

In this dataset, each ID represents a user, and variable refers to the function (e.g., x1, x2, x3), with Favourite indicating whether the function was executed via the app or the website.
I pivot the data to count how many actions were performed via APP or WEB:
(
    df
    .pivot(
        index=["ID"],
        on="Favourite",
        values=["variable"],
        aggregate_function=pl.col("Favourite").len()
    ).fill_null(0)
)

Output:
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ ID  ┆ APP ┆ WEB │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ u32 ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 0   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

Next, I calculate the proportion of app usage for each user and classify them:
(
    df2
    .with_columns(
        Total = pl.col("APP") + pl.col("WEB")
    )
    .with_columns(
        Proportion = pl.col("APP") / pl.col("Total")
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl
        .when(pl.col("Proportion") >= 0.6).then(pl.lit("APP Lover"))
        .when(pl.col("Proportion") > 0.1).then(pl.lit("BOTH"))
        .otherwise(pl.lit("Inactive"))
    )
)

shape: (3, 6)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ ID  ┆ APP ┆ WEB ┆ Total ┆ Proportion ┆ literal   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ u32 ┆ u32 ┆ u32   ┆ f64        ┆ str       │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╪════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 0   ┆ 3     ┆ 1.0        ┆ APP Lover │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 3     ┆ 0.666667   ┆ APP Lover │
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3     ┆ 0.333333   ┆ BOTH      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────┴────────────┴───────────┘

The challenge: In my real dataset, I have at least 19 different x variables. Yesterday asked, I tried iterating over all possible combinations of these variables to filter out the ones that result in the highest number of "APP Lovers," but the number of combinations (2^19) is too large to compute efficiently.
Question: How can I efficiently determine the best combination of xn variables that maximizes the number of "APP Lovers"? I'm looking for guidance on how to approach this in terms of algorithmic optimization or more efficient iterations.

Are the "x" variables associated with a user (and you want to find out which users are more likely to be app lovers)?

The x variables represent different functions that users may or may not utilize. I want to determine which functions to prioritize in order to maximize the number of APP users.

So, could there be multiple rows for the same user and x value?

@Hericks yes, each row contains an user, a functions, and where he rather use it

How about for each function, you compute the fraction of users that prefer to use it via app? Moreover, you could compute the total number of function usage. This way, you get a view on which functions are (a) mostly used via app and (b) frequently used overall.

Is 19 already too large to compute efficiently? 2^19 is only half a million. How many variables do you really have? And what do you consider efficient?

It’s not just about which function is used more; it’s really about how they work together. For example, if I pick two functions, x1 and x2, where the app is the overall favorite, some users might rather using x1 in the app but prefer the web for x2. This could really change the final results!

@nocomment On my work laptop im running out of ram , thats why im looking for some advice

the poster is confusing/mixing 2^19 with 19! (which is the number mentioned y'day), 2^19 obviously many order of magnitude smaller than 19!

This is doable easily in time proportional to 2^19 * 19 * num_users, and an optimization can remove the extra factor of 19. If you have, say, 1000000 users, that’s around 10^13 work (10^12 after the mentioned optimization) - doable in a few hours on a decent machine.

How many users do you have?

@nocomment around 450000

Here's my suggestion, take the data:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    "variable": ["x1", "x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x3", "x3", "x3"],
    "favorite": ["APP", "APP", "WEB", "APP", "WEB", "APP", "APP", "APP", "WEB"]
})

and pivot it such that column xi is true if user id uses that action primarily through the app:
action_through_app = (
    df
    .with_columns(pl.col.favorite == "APP")
    .pivot(index="id", on="variable", values="favorite")
)

For example:
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ x1    ┆ x2    ┆ x3    │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ true  ┆ true  ┆ true  │
│ 2   ┆ true  ┆ false ┆ true  │
│ 3   ┆ false ┆ true  ┆ false │
└─────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘

Now we can efficiently query if given some combination variables how many users would be app lovers by summing the relevant columns and checking if their sums are >= 0.6 * the number of columns.
def num_app_lovers(combination):
    return (pl.sum_horizontal(combination) >= 0.6*len(combination)).sum()

action_through_app.select(
    num_app_lovers([pl.col.x1]).alias("x1"),
    num_app_lovers([pl.col.x2]).alias("x2"),
    num_app_lovers([pl.col.x3]).alias("x3"),
    num_app_lovers([pl.col.x1, pl.col.x2]).alias("x12"),
    num_app_lovers([pl.col.x2, pl.col.x3]).alias("x23"),
    num_app_lovers([pl.col.x1, pl.col.x3]).alias("x13"),
    num_app_lovers([pl.col.x1, pl.col.x2, pl.col.x3]).alias("x123"),
)

shape: (1, 7)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ x1  ┆ x2  ┆ x3  ┆ x12 ┆ x23 ┆ x13 ┆ x123 │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ u32 ┆ u32 ┆ u32 ┆ u32 ┆ u32 ┆ u32 ┆ u32  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2    │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘

Now this lets you query combinations in bulk, but this still doesn't scale well to 2^19 possible combinations. For that problem I'd suggest using evolutionary programming.
Initialize a pool of possible combinations with x1, x2, x3, ... xn. Then, randomly add or remove a column (if > 1 column) to each combination in your pool, and test them with the above query. Keep the top, say, 100 combinations. Repeat this process for a bunch of iterations until the result no longer improves, and return that.

I just combined your approach of booleans with the iteration of the list, using .select() to filter the desired columns

In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/79086783/ - you can avoid materializing Python lists.
pl.concat(
    action_through_app
     .select(combo)
     .select(
         (pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all()) >= 0.6*pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all().is_not_null()))
            .sum().alias("target")
     )
     for combo in all_combinations
).with_row_index()

shape: (7, 2)
┌───────┬────────┐
│ index ┆ target │
│ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ u32   ┆ u32    │
╞═══════╪════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 2      │
│ 1     ┆ 2      │
│ 2     ┆ 2      │
│ 3     ┆ 1      │
│ 4     ┆ 1      │
│ 5     ┆ 2      │
│ 6     ┆ 2      │
└───────┴────────┘

If you use a LazyFrame, you can use pl.collect_all() to parallelize the selections.
lf = action_through_app.lazy()

pl.concat(
    pl.collect_all(
        lf
         .select(combo)
         .select(
             (pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all()) >= 0.6*pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all().is_not_null()))
                .sum().alias("target")
         )
         for combo in all_combinations
    )
).with_row_index()


The row index should be the same of the list index? Im trying this, however, when i manually put the list, im getting different resutls.

Should be. Just noticed you have a unique which will be a "random order" each time it runs. states = df["variable"].unique() - you probably want unique(maintain_order=True) to guarantee the same order.

Following @orlp's approach, I would pivot as suggested, create a full combination, and then use the .select() method to filter the columns.
import polars as pl
import itertools

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    "variable": ["x1", "x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x3", "x3", "x3"],
    "favorite": ["APP", "APP", "WEB", "APP", "WEB", "APP", "APP", "APP", "WEB"]
})

action_through_app = (
    df
    .with_columns(pl.col.favorite == "APP")
    .pivot(index="id", on="variable", values="favorite")
)

all_combinations = []

states = df["variable"].unique().to_list()
for r in range(1,len(states)+1):
    all_combinations.extend(itertools.combinations(states, r))

def test_f(df):
    return(
        df.with_columns((pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all()) >= 0.6*pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all().is_not_null())).alias("target"))
    )

new_rows = []

for i in range(len(all_combinations)):
    df_filtered = action_through_app.select(all_combinations[i])
    df_test = test_f(df_filtered).select(pl.col("target").sum()).to_series().to_list()
    x = df_test[0]
    new_rows.append({"loop_index": i, "size": x})
    
df_final = pl.DataFrame(new_rows)

This way i have this output:
shape: (7, 2)
┌────────────┬──────┐
│ loop_index ┆ size │
│ ---        ┆ ---  │
│ i64        ┆ i64  │
╞════════════╪══════╡
│ 0          ┆ 2    │
│ 1          ┆ 2    │
│ 2          ┆ 2    │
│ 3          ┆ 1    │
│ 4          ┆ 2    │
│ 5          ┆ 1    │
│ 6          ┆ 2    │
└────────────┴──────┘


You could probably improve things by avoiding materializing Python lists: pl.concat(df.select(c).select((pl.sum_horizontal() >= ...).sum().alias("target")) for c in combos) and if you use LazyFrame, you could pl.concat(pl.collect_all(...)) to parallelize the selections.

@jqurious Could you provide the full code please

Well it was too large for a comment, I've added it as a temporary answer. If you want to test it out and incorporate it into this answer I can then delete it.
